# How to calculate a similarity score between two users rating films

Tags: recommender-system, similarities

This is probably a standard problem for a seasoned data scientist or statistician, but I'm stuck right at the beginning:

Suppose I have two users (A and B) on a site like IMDB, where they can rate a movie from 1 to 10 (10 being best). Now I want to see for two users how "similar" or "compatible" they are. To do that I want to calculate a score that takes into account how A and B have rated films - looking only at films that BOTH have rated. If both users have rated all films exactly the same, the score should be highest. If they have rated all films as differently as possible, that score should be lowest.

One way to approach this would be to calculated the average of all (absolute) differences. So that when A has rated film 1 an 8 and film 2 a 3 and B has rated film 1 an 5 and film 2 a 4 the average of all differences would be (|8-5|+|3-4|)/2 = 2.

This seems to be awefully simple so I assume there must be a better way to calculate such a similarity score.

After researching a bit I tried using "cosine distance", but I find that this gives worse results, where diametrically different ratings end up having a high score.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with the average absolute difference? Simplicity is a virtue not a problem. In fact there are many ways for doing this and pros and cons can be argued, but the average absolute difference surely is a valid option. (An issue with this is that two users will always be very different if one rates everything high and the other one rates everything low, but they prefer the same films - depending on the data not many of such pairs that you feel are really "done wrong" may exist. And depending on what you want similarity to mean you may find it just appropriate.)

Comment: The key issue here is not to do something sophisticated backed up by some convoluted theory, but rather to choose something that reflects as precisely as possible the meaning you want it to reflect.

Comment: Good point - maybe you're right and a simple solution is in this case indeed a good (enough) solution. (Interesting issue that you mention. I think I will assume that all user exhaust the full range of scores, so that point can be neglected).